# What are the power requirements for a Carpenter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

The [forestry wiki](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki/index.php?n=Machines.Carpenter) does not specify. Is a redstone engine sufficient?

Comment: Needs to be powered by a BuildCraft compatible engine... whatever that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I believe a redstone engine is indeed sufficient, you're probably going to want to juice it some more.

I've found that a Hobbyist's Steam Engine (2 MJ/t) (from Railcraft) performs well enough, but having at least a Commercial Steam Engine (4 MJ/t) (also Railcraft) is usually handy to get some real speed on the crafting.